# React Restful api is making problem with json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

I have been trying all sort of things but this is first time this happens. I spend days on google and youtube to find something but nothing works nor one opinion nor many all together or some kind of combinations.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("../public/data.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => 
        console.log(data);
      );
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

And the error is:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving your fetch call a relative path to a file.  This needs to be your API endpoint.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("../public/data.json") // this needs to be a url
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => 
        console.log(data);
      );
  }
```

if you have the JSON file locally already and just want your React Component to have access to it, then just import it `import jsonData from "../public/data.json"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get data from a local `json` file you don't need to use `fetch` method. You can simply `import` your file.

You thus don't need to use `fetch` method in your componentDidMount. In the future if you want to use `fetch` method you have to remember that `fetch` takes an url. I provide you a valid url to show you an example.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import json from "../public/data.json";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => 
        console.log(data);
      );

    console.log(json); // print your Json file
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 'require' to import your JSON file, if it is local.

E.g.: `const data = require('../public/data.json')`. console.log(data) will return the entire JSON object.

Edit: One thing to remember is that require() will always cache the content of the loaded module (or file, in this case). The next time require() is called again, it will restore it from the cache instead of reading it again.

Answer (score 0):

On a contrary with other answers, `fetch("../public/data.json")` is a valid url. The only problem is that it will take current url in the browser, go one level up (e.g. remove content after last `/`) and append `public/data.json`, then try to fetch the resource. So the error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` comes from trying to parse html (most likely `<!doctype html>` as json